# How to get all arguments as one in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

My python 3 script receives many arguments, number is not known beforehand.
I know how to read them separately using argparse or argv[x] but how can I get them all as one string?

e.g. with

```
python3 p.py first -second and more -and maybe another okay thisisthelast one
```

I would like to get as one string:

```
first -second and more -and maybe another okay thisisthelast one
```

Comment: This appears to be XY. What are you intending on doing with the string? Aside, the typical way to parse CLI arguments is with the `argparse` builtin library.

Comment: Off the top of my head (without testing): As a string could be: `' '.join(argv[1:])`.

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sys module of python3.

```
import sys
print(*sys.argv[1:])
```

sample output:

```
python3 test.py hello -v
hello -v
```